# Migrate Android webview to React-Native-Webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-webkit, react-native-bridge

I have a **Hybrid Android App** which uses Android **WebView** for rendering the Web Pages.

I have **Wiziwig Editor** (which is written in HTML, javascript, and css). I am using **Webkit Interface** for communicating between Java and JavaScript

I want to integrate **React Native** in my Editor. Previously I was using JavaScript models and JS functions for implementing various functionalities in the WiziWig Editor and manipulating DOM.

But its UX is not fast and appealing. Moreover, I had integrated the **Twitter BloodHound Engine** in Editor. Whenever the user types in the Editor the typeahead list of BloodHound Engine lags.

I am thinking of using the React Native in my Editor. With React Native I can also use the Android Native components for showing messages and other things instead of the JavaScript Models. There are also other possibilities of improvement with React Native.

I built a demo app in which, I am able to communicate between Java and Javascript code using React Native Modules.

*Question*

My WiziWig has so much Code already written in HTML, CSS, and plain JavaScript. In order to convert my code to React Native and using Native components for UI, it would take a lot of time.

Is there a way in which I can use my old code base in React Native and then I slowly move the code to the React Native using JSX and components.

I have seen There is **Render function** in React Native for Rendering the html content. But I have to write the plain JS code in JSX. Is there a fast way to do it. Because my file has already 4495 lines of Code.

Thanks in advance